# Why does AngularJS $http .success promise work but .then doesn't?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I've been using the following code for doing ajax calls in Angular which worked fine so far:

```
  function getData (url) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url, {
      cache: true
    }).success(function (data) {
      deferred.resolve(data); // works
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

As you can see there is only a success handler. When I wanted to add an error handler, I noticed that the docs state that `success` and `error` were depracated and should not be used any more (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Instead the `.then` promise should be used, so I changed my code to this:

```
  function getData (url) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http.get(url, {
      cache: true
    }).then(function (data) {
      deferred.resolve(data); // Not called :(
    }, function () {
      deferred.resolve(false); // Not called :(
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Now everything stopped working. `.then` is never called. Why? I'm on latest Angular version 1.4

Comment: Why are you creating a new deferred in the first place? $http itself returns one.

Comment: @KevinB Hm, true that, I guess I could omit it. However, that doesn't solve my problem :-)

Comment: Indeed it doesn't. Your syntax looks correct, .then should be getting called, either error or success.

Comment: although... have you placed a debugging statement into each of those callbacks to make sure they aren't being called rather than relying on the extra deferred resolving/rejecting?

Comment: @KevinB I did but didn't see the msg in console. I'll remove the unused promise now and try again.

Comment: @KevinB Got it to work (see my answer) thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem. Actually, there were two problems.

First, I had a redundant promise which I removed:

```
  function getData (url) {
    return $http.get(url, {cache: true});
  }
```

Second, the returned data from `.then` seems to be a little different from `.success`. Instead of returning the plain result data, it returns an object with some meta data from the call. So, in order to get the data, I'd have to access `data.data`:

```
  pub.getList = function () {
    return getData(serviceurl + "?c=latest").then(function (result) {
      var list = result.data;
      precacheArticles(list);
      return list;
    });
  };
```

Comment: As @KevinB suggested in the original question, there is still a promise anti-pattern here where the `pub.getList` returns a thenable (promise) which wraps an existing thenable. Why not just return `getData(...)`?

Comment: If the purpose of the second deferred was to transform the data, that can also be done without the second deferred. `deferred.resolve(data.data);` becomes `return data.data`

Comment: @Matt Because I need to call `precacheArticles(data.data);` before I return the promise.

Comment: @KevinB Just replace resolve() with return? What's the benefit?

Comment: The benefit is you have one less deferred object.

Comment: @KevinB That doesn't work. Breaks my app because the caller of `getList()` is waiting for the promise to fulfill but that never happens because I removed `.resolve()` and replaced with `return data.data;`.

Comment: you missed the point. remove the second deferred object and return getData directly! basically, you had two redundant promises. you fixed one in your first snippet, now do the same in the second.

Comment: @KevinB I think you missed the point. If I directly return the promise, I cannot call `precacheArticles(data.data);` before returning the promise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87419/discussion-between-kevin-b-and-timo).